# Why can't I connect into mysql in docker container?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

Given is a `docker-compose.yml` spawning up a Percona/Mysql database with the following credentials:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  mysqltest:
    image: percona:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:-nopassword}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
      - MYSQL_USER=test
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
```

After `docker-compose up` I see that this database was created, mysql launched and that the root account has no password.

So I tried to connect from my Host into this container:

`mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -p`
`mysql -h127.0.0.1 -utest -ptest`
`mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -p`
`mysql -hlocalhost -utest -ptest`

Nothing works.

```
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

How can I connect into containerised mysql database from my host?

Answer (score 2):

You need to expose the ports as well

```
    image: percona:5.7
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html):

> A MySQL client on Unix can connect to the mysqld server in two different ways: By using a Unix socket file to connect through a file in the file system (default /tmp/mysql.sock), or by using TCP/IP, which connects through a port number. A Unix socket file connection is faster than TCP/IP, but can be used only when connecting to a server on the same computer. A Unix socket file is used if you do not specify a host name or if you specify the special host name localhost.

As a result, there are two situations here:

- **-h127.0.0.1**

  For this, you need to expose the container port `3306` to host port `3306` as next, so your `mysql client` on host could access it:

  ```
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  ```
- **-hlocahost OR not define -h**

  For this, you need to let host have ways to access unix socket in container, something like next:

  ```
  $ pwd
  /home/shubuntu1/20210827
  $ mkdir mysql && chmod 777 mysql
  $ docker-compose up
  ```

  **docker-compose.yaml:**

  ```
  version: '3.4'

  services:
    mysqltest:
      image: percona:5.7
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:-nopassword}
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
        - MYSQL_USER=test
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
      volumes:
        - $PWD/mysql:/var/lib/mysql/
  ```

  With this way, the unix socket `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` could be visit in host with `/home/shubuntu1/20210827/mysql/mysql.sock`.

  According to mysql help:

  > -S, --socket=name   The socket file to use for connection.

  You then, could use next to connect to mysql in container:

  ```
  $ mysql -S /home/shubuntu1/20210827/mysql/mysql.sock -utest -p
  ```